# react-datepicker select time range for single day

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-datepicker

I am using react-datepicker to build a booking system component. Users can select a day and select a start time and end time (both start and end time can only be in the same day).

I would like to show only one datepicker and then two timepicker, but only manage to get two full components (date+time).

My code:

```
const StartTime () => {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
  return (
    <DatePicker
      selected={startDate}
      onChange={date => setStartDate(date)}
      showTimeSelect
      timeFormat="HH:mm"
      timeIntervals={15}
      timeCaption="time"
      dateFormat="MMMM d, yyyy h:mm aa"
    />
  );
};

const EndTime () => {
  const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState(new Date());
  return (
    <DatePicker
      selected={endDate}
      onChange={date => setEndDate(date)}
      showTimeSelect
      timeFormat="HH:mm"
      timeIntervals={15}
      timeCaption="time"
      dateFormat="MMMM d, yyyy h:mm aa"
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: https://reactdatepicker.com/ some of the examples on the home page should get you what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 1 date only picker and two time only pickers.
You will need to validate the start time to be before the end.

Date only picker

```
   const date () => {
      const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
      return (
        <DatePicker selected={startDate} onChange={date => setStartDate(date)} />
      );
    };
```

Time only Picker

```
const EndTime() => {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
  return (
    <DatePicker
      selected={startDate}
      onChange={date => setStartDate(date)}
      showTimeSelect
      showTimeSelectOnly
      timeIntervals={15}
      timeCaption="Time"
      dateFormat="h:mm aa"
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: this still gives me something like ```Sun Oct 04 2020 16:45:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)```I only need the time not the day

Comment: you should use ```dateFormat="h:mm a"``` instead of ```dateFormat="h:mm aa"``` because of you will get "5:05 pmpm" in the first case.